# C# String.replace is not working

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have this string from which I want to remove the Hosting html part.

```
string r = @"2014-09-18 20:59:53|
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php""></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->";
```

But

```
r = r.Replace(
@"<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php""></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->","");
```

Is not working. I get the same annoying original string.This has been driving me crazy

Comment: I believe you are trying to extract Date from your string, why not do `string date = r.Split('|').First();`

Comment: Compare the strings at runtime. Hint: whitespace.

Comment: Note that, for multiline @ strings like this to work the way you want them to, they *can't be indented.*  See http://ideone.com/ffyQuA

Comment: And what result do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've posted does remove the string as you are trying to.  You can verify this yourself here.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/p4lchi

The string you are ultimately examining must come from some other source.

Comment: Your fiddle happens to work because you indented both @ strings in exactly the same way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  Yes, that is a necessary condition.  The shown code also has that property.

Comment: shouldn't that be a comment. I mean your answer could be "your current code works fine, the problem is elsewhere"

Comment: @recursive: If the posted code really had that property, it would have worked already.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, that's my point.  It *does* work already.

Comment: @EmpereurAiman: You used the @ symbol, which means "This is exactly how I want this multiline string to look, indentation and all."

Answer (score 1):

From examining your string, it appears you're trying to remove everything after the first `bar` character. If that's the case, this might work better:

```
r = r.Split('|')[0];
```